# How to use LLVM to generate a call graph?

Tags: llvm, static-analysis, call-graph

I'm looking into generating a call-graph for the linux kernel that would include function pointers (see my previous question [Static call graph generation for the Linux kernel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9470871/static-call-graph-generation-for-the-linux-kernel) for more information). I've been told LLVM should be suitable for this purpose, however I was unable to find the relevant information on llvm.org

Any help, including pointers to relevant documentation, would be appreciated.

Answer (score 17):

First, you have to compile your kernel into LLVM IR (instead of native object files). Then, using `llvm-ld`, combine all the IR object files into a single large module. It could be quite a tricky thing to do, you'll have to modify the makefiles heavily, but I believe it is doable.

Now you can do your analysis. A simple call graph can be generated using the `opt` tool with `-dot-callgraph` pass. It is unlikely to handle function pointers, so you may want to modify it.

Tracking all the possible data flow paths that would carry your function pointers is quite a challenge, and in general case it is impossible to do (if there are any pointer to integer casts, if pointers are stored in complicated data structures, etc.). For a majority of specific cases you can try to implement a global abstract interpretation to approximate all the possible data flow paths for your pointers. It would not be accurate, of course, but then you'll get at least a conservative approximation.

Comment: You really don't want to produce a dot callgraph for 8 million lines of code. It would cover a tennis cour, if dot could draw it, which it can't. Other than that, this is a great echo of the answer to the other question note by OP :-} with special emphasis on what fun function pointers are.

Comment: @IraBaxter, certainly you don't want to *display* a dot callgraph for anything bigger than "hello, world!". But you may want to use that .dot file for your further analysis. I normally parse .dot files and store them into a database.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the `opt` tool.
Yes, Ira, I'm not looking into generating a graphical representation of the call graph. Having it in any parsable format is OK, which the dot format qualifies for. 

Concerning function pointers, I have been told that LLVM should be able to do some of that points-to analysis for function pointers. I am not looking into implementing this myself, clearly.

Comment: `llvm-ld` is deprecated, use `llvm-link` or gold plugin instead.